# SQL Insert Row In-between Two Rows

Tags: sql

How do I insert a row between here?

[image]

Comment: SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as "between" two rows.

Comment: Is there any way to move another row in between 2 rows?

Comment: . . What part of "unordered set" do you not understand?  You can construct a query to return the results in a particular order, but rows are inserted into a table; there is no ordering.

Comment: The only way you can have specific order in your rows is if you add a new column (eg rowNumber) and alter the value of this rowNumber column. Of course you will have to do sorting on your select statements if you need the data sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Data is not intended to be stored SQL tables in any particular order, so it's not appropriate to insert a row at a particular position. You use an SQL SELECT query to extract the data you want and ORDER BY to specify how it is sorted. If you really want to have this row in a particular position, add an ID column as the primary key and number the ID column values in the sequence that you want. Whatever you are using to view your rows will order them by the ID column by default. However, you're going to experience this same problem every time you want to add a new row as SQL tables are not intended to be used in this way.